Tensorflow dataset module
I am trying to load dataset in TensorFlow, I have installed Tensorflow datasets using anaconda framework and also using this command conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-datasets but it is showing me error:

Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
done.

The Python version I'm using is:
python        3.10.14
tensorflow  2.16.1  pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-datasets 4.9.4   pypi_0    pypi
I also tried using pip install but still not working and getting this error while running my program in Juypter.
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 5
      2 import tensorflow as tf
      3 from tensorflow import keras
----> 5 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
      6 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score 
      7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'


what's the output of pip install tensorflow-datasets ?

This is the output in command prompt: Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-datasets in c:\users\jwf3350\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in c:\users\jwf3350\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\jwf3350\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets) (8.1.7)
c:\users\jwf3350\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from etils[enp,epath,etree]>=0.9.0->tensorflow-datasets) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in

Do you confirm that you are running the jupyter server in the same conda environment where you installed tensorflow-datasets?

I am using Google Colab with TensorFlow version 2.17.1, and the code is
executing successfully. I have attached the gist for your reference. Please
let me know if you're still facing any issues.
